# In Angular 4 how we can change the parent component value when we are in child component?

Tags: angular

In Angular 4 how we can change the parent component value  when we are  in child component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update parent component property from child component in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464871/update-parent-component-property-from-child-component-in-angular-2)

Comment: sir, i need this in angular 4

Comment: One of possible options is - both components may share same service: https://stackblitz.com/edit/two-sibling-components

Comment: 2 way data-binding is available in angular 4 aswell and is working just like that

Comment: Do you have some code to show ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `@Output` and `EventEmitters` to send data from a child components to it's parent. You can find tutorials on the offical [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**child-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output,EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';

    export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
        @Output() parentValue = new EventEmitter<string>();

      onChange() {
              this.parentValue.emit("test");
        }
    }
```

**parent-component.html**

```
<app-parent (parentValue)="parentValue"></app-parent>
```